# PHP/MySQL - Get multiple fields from one entry in a table

Tags: php, mysql, select

I thought I could find loads of examples on how to do this but nothing I find tells me how to get the values in PHP.

Say I have this code:

```
$query = "SELECT name, age FROM people WHERE id = 2";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

How do I get the data from $result?

Pseudo code:

```
$name = $result['name'];
$age = $result['age'];
```

Comment: Have a look at [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) and have a look at the red box. Please consider using mysqli or PDO right from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
$query = "SELECT name, age FROM people WHERE id = 2";    
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['name'];
echo $row['age'];
```

Comment: Thank you, I will accept this answer when it lets me in 9min.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a row from the result first. You can get a number-based array using [`mysql-fetch-row`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) or an associative array using [`mysql-fetch-assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).

```
$query = "SELECT name, age FROM people WHERE id = 2";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$name = $row['name'];
$age = $row['age'];
```

To note: the `mysql` functions are deprecated. You should use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.